# How to configure nginx to serve from file based on cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on an ecommerce platform that has dynamic content for logged in users, but for logged out users many pages such as product pages and category pages are relatively static.

Rails has been configured to save copies of specific logged out pages to disk when accessed.

I would like nginx to serve these files when it detects a logged out user. We have a cookie set on users when they are logged in, so my hope was that I could check for this.

My 'ideal' nginx configuration would look something like (in a server block):

```
location /my_location { 
    if (!$cookie_user_logged_in) { 
        try_files /cached_pages/$uri /cached_pages/$uri.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @rails_application; 
    } 
}
```

However, that is not valid, because as far as I can tell, based on research and error messages, one cannot put try_files inside an if.

**Is there a way to accomplish this with nginx?**

I have been told that I should do this with another tool such as Varnish. I also know that I could do things with action caching in Rails, and fragment caching to get close to the same end. However, I would like to determine if this is a viable option before adding to the tech stack or investing further in development.